# Intel AC 7260 issue (WiFi hang if Bluetooth on)

Tags: bluetooth, intel

Hello I have AC 7260 Wireless adapter.
With Bluetooth turned off, everything works fine, but when Bluetooth is turned on, after a short random time (about a minute or three), the network freezes and restarting NetworkManager does not help. Wireless start working only after restart pc.
I tried to disable the bluetooth driver (device) but had no meaningful success.

Ubuntu  version

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

WiFi driver (firmware)

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
 
[    6.283159] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.465644] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    6.486261] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 34:f6:4b:b8:7b:ee
[    6.724114] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlmvm doesn't allow to disable HW crypto, check swcrypto module parameter
[    6.724122] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlmvm doesn't allow to disable BT Coex, check bt_coex_active module parameter
[    6.727993] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.825950] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Answer (score 1):

create in /etc/modprobe.d/  a file which has the suffix .conf.

```
 options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1
```

The first parameter is Disabling Bluetooth Coexistence and the second use
crypto in software

```
modinfo iwlwifi | fgrep parm
```

shows more parameter for this moudule. sorry I'm not good in explainning in english.

Comment: `swcrypto=1` is not usefull here.